# How to select only enabled checkbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 set of `checkboxes` (consider one as "main checkbox" and other as "sub checkbox") that are created dynamically by PHP with data fetched from database.

When the page loads, the "sub checkboxes" are disabled by default and it will be enabled only when the respective main checkbox is checked.

For example - "Monday, Tuesday...Friday" will be the "main checkboxes".

`"9:00 AM -10:00 AM", "10:00 AM -11:00 AM", "11:00 AM -12:00 PM", "12:00 PM -01:00 PM"` will be the "sub checkboxes".

Whenever one of the "sub checkboxes" is checked then its related checkbox of a weekday also should be checked but only the enabled checkbox must be checked.

I have added the demo in JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Anji12/xdo0fzvc/15/

The `checkboxes` are getting checked but even the disabled ones are also checked. How to not check disabled `checkboxes`?

I tried using the below code but it does not work.

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    if(!$("." + selectedSlot).is('[disabled]')){
        $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", false);
    }else{
        $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", true);
    }
} else {
    $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", false);
}         

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="1" name="day[]" value="1" /> Monday
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday1" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='1' > 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday1" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='2' > 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday1" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='3' > 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday1" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='4' > 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="2" name="day[]" value="2" /> Tuesday
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday2" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='1' > 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday2" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='2' > 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday2" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='3' > 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday2" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='4' > 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="3" name="day[]" value="3" /> Wednesday
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday3" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='1' > 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday3" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='2' > 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday3" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='3' > 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday3" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='4' > 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="4" name="day[]" value="4" /> Thursday
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday4" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='1' > 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday4" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='2' > 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday4" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='3' > 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday4" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='4' > 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="5" name="day[]" value="5" /> Friday
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday5" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='1' > 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday5" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='2' > 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday5" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='3' > 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday5" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]"  value='4' > 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. The given excerpt lacks the markup needed, and the information how that code is called

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added the html code and also created the demo of working in JSFiddle  - https://jsfiddle.net/Anji12/xdo0fzvc/15/

Comment: Generically, you can select enabled, unchecked checkboxes with `$('input:checkbox:not(:checked):enabled')`. See [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) and [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and more broadly [Form selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/). Reading the documentation helps...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have tried with $('input:checkbox:not(:checked):enabled') too, but the result is same, does not work.

Comment: Right. That was a hint, not an answer. You were meant to refer to the documentation, read it, understand it, and apply it yourself to your situation. That way you would learn and be able to answer these questions yourself rather than asking a question every time you had a question and didn't feel like reading...

Comment: Adding `:enabled` worked first time on your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zc8r59ds/

Comment: Please check this fiddle .
It will check sub boxes if enable and one of the related checkbox will checked
https://jsfiddle.net/rgyj9vwt/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through all `checkboxes` and check for `disabled` for attribute and then decide to add `checked` prop or not.

```
 $("." + selectedSlot).each((e, el) => {
             var maininput = $(el).is('[disabled]')
             if (!maininput)
                   $(el).prop("checked", true);
                })
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/7tbLvk1r/

Try this one:

```js
$(".slot").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".day").click(function () {
            let day = $(this).data('day');
            let dd = "weekday" + day
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("." + dd).prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $("." + dd).prop("disabled", true);
                $("." + dd).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });

        $(".slot").click(function () {
            let slot = $(this).data('slot_time');
            let selectedSlot = "selectedSlot" + slot;

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("." + selectedSlot).each((e, el) => {
                    var maininput = $(el).is('[disabled]')
                    if (!maininput)
                        $(el).prop("checked", true);
                })
            } else {
                $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="1" name="day[]" value="1" /> Monday
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday1" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='1'> 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday1" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='2'> 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday1" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='3'> 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday1" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='4'> 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="2" name="day[]" value="2" /> Tuesday
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday2" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='1'> 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday2" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='2'> 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday2" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='3'> 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday2" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='4'> 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="3" name="day[]" value="3" /> Wednesday
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday3" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='1'> 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday3" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='2'> 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday3" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='3'> 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday3" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='4'> 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="4" name="day[]" value="4" /> Thursday
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday4" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='1'> 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday4" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='2'> 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday4" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='3'> 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday4" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='4'> 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type='checkbox' class="day" data-day="5" name="day[]" value="5" /> Friday
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday5" data-slot_time="1" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='1'> 9:00 AM -10:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-1">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot2 weekday5" data-slot_time="2" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='2'> 10:00 AM -11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot3 weekday5" data-slot_time="3" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='3'> 11:00 AM -12:00 PM
                </label>
                <label class="form-check-label py-3">
                    <input class="slot selectedSlot4 weekday5" data-slot_time="4" type="checkbox" name="slot_from[]" value='4'> 12:00 PM -01:00 PM
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is what `:enabled` is for: `$("." + selectedSlot + ":enabled").prop("checked", true)`

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, your suggestion too worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong?**
In your html, there is no differences (except class names). So in the js, the selector select all slots beacuse they are same.

```
$(".slot").click(function() {
  let slot=$(this).data('slot_time');
  let selectedSlot ="selectedSlot"+slot;

  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", false);
  }                   
});
```

**What did I change?**
I added `data-week-day="#"` attributes to all slots (according to their day). Then edit the js like below

```
$(".slot").click(function () {
    let slot = $(this).data('slot_time');
    let selectedSlot = "selectedSlot" + slot;
    let selectedDates = $('.day[data-day]:checked');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.each(selectedDates, function (k, v) {
            $("." + selectedSlot + ".weekday"+$(v).attr('data-day')).prop("checked", true);
        })
    } else {
        $.each(selectedDates, function (k, v) {
            $("." + selectedSlot + ".weekday"+$(v).attr('data-day')).prop("checked", false);
        })
    }
});
```

There must be the easier way for this question, I hope I could explain
Here is the working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2qr1uh9x/

Comment: `$("." + selectedSlot + " ."+selectedWeekDay)` is the same as `this`.  OP wants to select all the same slot across all active days.  So if they enable Monday+Friday then click 9:00AM on Monday it also selects 9:00AM on Friday.  At the moment, OP is selecting Mon/Tue/Wed etc even if they're not *enabled*.

Comment: the related checkboxes are not selecting, even if the main checkbox is enabled.

Comment: I made a few changes, check out the JsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/2qr1uh9x/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you just need to loop all the checkboxes add one condition to check sub checkboxes are disabled or not... [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/v97d02rL/3/)

```
$(".slot").click(function() {
  let slot=$(this).data('slot_time');
  let selectedSlot ="selectedSlot"+slot;

  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    $( "." + selectedSlot ).each(function( index ) {
        if($(this).prop('disabled')===false){
           $(this).prop("checked", true);
         }
     });
  } else {
    $("." + selectedSlot).prop("checked", false);
  }                   
});
```

Comment: This is what `:enabled` is for:  `$("." + selectedSlot + ":enabled").prop("checked", true)`

Answer (score -1):

Explanation,
I'm saying that the class name of every check box is similar that's why it's selecting all the checkbox of that class so put another class name.

Please Add Another name here,

Your all input class like this
class="slot selectedSlot1 weekday1"
So, Please Set Another name in all
Example,

### Monday > input class like this

class="slot **selectedSlotMonday** weekday1"

### Tuesday

class="slot **selectedSlotTuesday** weekday1"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Note, you can simply [edit] your existing answer and undelete it rather than posting a new answer. Also, please read [answer] and [How to format my posts in Markdown and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information on how to format code.